# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

I keep getting that error on the fillInAddress function.

This is my form html:

```
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" width="500px"></input>
</div>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs" class="new_job" id="new_job" method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_address">Customer</label><br>
    <input id="customer" name="job[address]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_address">Address</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="street_name" name="job[address]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_route">Route</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="route" name="job[route]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_city">City</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="locality" name="job[city]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_state">State</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="job[state]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_postal_code">Postal code</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="postal_code" name="job[postal_code]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_country">Country</label><br>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="country" name="job[country]" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Job" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And my JS:

```
    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
```

The form fields are supposed to populate when I select a result from the autocomplete input field. However, that's not happening. When I directly cut and paste the code from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform, it work's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

The first property of `componentForm` is `street_number`. You do not have any element in your HTML with an ID of `street_number`.

Therefore `document.getElementById(component)` returns null, and `document.getElementById(component).value` causes you to reference property `value` of `null`, which causes the error.

It looks like the correct name of the property should be `street_name`, based on your form.

Comment: I was just about to answer this myself. I see that now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know of a way to combine the `street_number` and `route` to populate a single input field?

Comment: Can't you just concatenate them? `var streetNumber = 1; var route = 'abc';` then in your component form do: `var street_name = streetNumber + ' ' + route;`

Comment: Or you can also do that in your `for` loop by checking if the component name is equal to a certain value, and then saying `document.getElementById(component).value = streetNumber + ' ' + route;`

Comment: I tried both of those, but I'm having a hard time getting it work. Any ideas?

Comment: I have this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/104543fbc0d65100cfee but it's obviously not working; I'm not sure where to put the `address` variable (your `street` variable in your jsfiddle). I have an input field with `id = address` now too that's supposed to combine `street_number` and `route`.

Comment: `for (var component in componentForm) {
    if (component == "street_number") { continue; }
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  document.getElementById("street_name").value = componentForm.street_number + ' ' + componentForm.route;`

Comment: Just do it outside of the loop, as above. The scope of variables within the loop will not include property names of things inside your object

Comment: I have this now: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6007d24db4543b3fc2c. It's placing `short_name long_name` (instead of the values) in the form field. It's also disabling it.

Comment: @user1034672 Give this a try (see comment on your github post https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6007d24db4543b3fc2c#comment-1204445)

Comment: You've been superhelpful, but it's not working. Any other ideas?